# Unexpected result in iText 5.5.5 and earlier when using list and specific font

Tags: java, pdf, itext

When I use the fonts in the example code below, the generated pdf doesn't show the results I expected (see comments in source code):

```
import java.io.BufferedOutputStream;
import java.io.File;
import java.io.FileOutputStream;
import java.io.IOException;

import com.itextpdf.text.BaseColor;
import com.itextpdf.text.Document;
import com.itextpdf.text.DocumentException;
import com.itextpdf.text.Font;
import com.itextpdf.text.FontFactory;
import com.itextpdf.text.ListItem;
import com.itextpdf.text.PageSize;
import com.itextpdf.text.pdf.BaseFont;
import com.itextpdf.text.pdf.PdfWriter;

public class PdfListTest {

    private File file;
    private Font font1;
    private Font font2;

    public PdfListTest() {
        file = new File("out.pdf");
        font1 = FontFactory.getFont(FontFactory.HELVETICA, BaseFont.WINANSI,
                BaseFont.NOT_EMBEDDED, 12, Font.UNDERLINE, BaseColor.GRAY, true);
        font2 = FontFactory.getFont(FontFactory.HELVETICA, BaseFont.WINANSI,
                BaseFont.NOT_EMBEDDED, 12, Font.STRIKETHRU, BaseColor.BLACK, true);
    }

    public void run() {
        try (
                FileOutputStream fos = new FileOutputStream(file);
                BufferedOutputStream bos = new BufferedOutputStream(fos)
            )
        {
            Document document = new Document(PageSize.A4);
            PdfWriter.getInstance(document, bos);
            document.addTitle("itext list test");
            document.addCreator("test");
            document.addAuthor("test");
            document.addSubject("test");

            document.open();

            com.itextpdf.text.List list = new com.itextpdf.text.List(true, 36);

            // 1. single line list item => shows expected behavior
            list.add(new ListItem("This is a test string", font1));
            list.add(new ListItem("This is a second test string", font2));

            // 2. double line list item => differs from expected behavior
            list.add(new ListItem("This is a test string\nThis is a test string", font1));
            list.add(new ListItem("This is a second test string\nThis is a second test string", font2));

            // 3. long line list item which gets wrapped => shows expected behavior
            list.add(new ListItem("This is a test string. This is a test string. This is a test string. This is a test string. This is a test string.", font1));
            list.add(new ListItem("This is a second test string. This is a second test string. This is a second test string. This is a second test string.", font2));

            document.add(list);
            document.close();

        } catch (DocumentException | IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        PdfListTest pdfTest = new PdfListTest();
        pdfTest.run();
    }

}
```

List item 3. and 4. only have underline or strikethrough in the last line of the list item text. I expected the same results as list item 5. and 6. are showing (both lines underlined or strikethrough).

Is this the expected behavior or a bug?

Comment: I can reproduce the "problem" but I can't say if it's deliberate behavior or a bug. A `ListItem` is a special type of `Paragraph`. You're not really supposed to add `\n` characters in a `Paragraph` as that would be like putting two paragraphs in one. I'll have to think if this is an issue we should fix or not.

Comment: @bruno-lowagie Ok, in my opinion it would be best to either disallow usage of newline character in this context or convert the two lines into two paragraphs internally. In this way no confusing results will be created.